# How can I get the ID of a option in a select field in a database?

Tags: notion-api

I want to update a database with the api and I have a multi select column... I want to add an option to a row in my table, but I can't figure out to how to get the ID of the specific option. [options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s20eQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the name of the options, so you would use:

```
{
  "Tags": {
    "multi_select": [
      {
        "name": "auth"
      },
      {
        "name": "video"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You don't need any ids for that:)